# Android adding to an arraylist

Tags: android

I have a chat program that displays I list of online users. The message back from the server is "RESP_USERLIST,,, etc.
Except I am having problems adding these usernames to my list.

Here is my current code:

```
List <String> responseList = Arrays.asList(OnlineUsersPost.split(","));
    if (responseList.contains("RESP_USERLIST")){
        _onlineUsers = responseList.get(1);

        System.out.println("Online users: " + _onlineUsers);
```

And where I initialise it:

```
private String _onlineUsers;
```

It seems it is only taking the first user and adding it to the list, I want to add them all to an arraylist.

EDIT: I have now tried it this way, with little difference:

```
List <String> responseList = Arrays.asList(OnlineUsersPost.split(","));
    if (responseList.contains("RESP_USERLIST")){
        for (int i = 0; i < responseList.size(); i++) {
            _onlineUsers.add(responseList.get(i));
            System.out.println("Online users: " + _onlineUsers);
        }
```

And where I initialise it:

```
private List<String> _onlineUsers;
```

Comment: what are you getting, and what is issue, please explain properly

Comment: The first code only gets the first entry (online user), and the second one crashes my program with "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity"

Comment: paste log cat as well, to find out why app is crashing

Comment: 04-07 14:56:36.695: E/AndroidRuntime(362): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-07 14:56:36.695: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
04-07 14:56:36.695: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-07 14:56:36.695: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-07 14:56:36.695: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-07 14:56:36.695: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

Comment: Should it be responseList.size() in the for loop? I'm having doubts about that part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You should initialize your arraylist first, initialization statement you are showing is only declaration, so initialize it as:

```
private List<String> _onlineUsers= new ArrayList<Sting>();
```

and change your loop to following:

```
ist <String> responseList = Arrays.asList(OnlineUsersPost.split(","));
    if (responseList.contains("RESP_USERLIST")){
        for (int i = 1; i < responseList.size(); i++) {
            _onlineUsers.add(responseList.get(i));
            System.out.println("Online users: " + _onlineUsers);
        }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!